# Neighbors of specific segment in a segmented image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Consider the output of a segmentation algorithm is a matrix with the same size as the input image. For each segment that is detected a specific part of the matrix is indexed with a specific number/index, look bellow.

I want to retrieve the neighbors of a specific segment. [Here](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/02/25/neighbor-indexing-2/) there is a description of taking the neighbors of each pixel in different sizes. For example, in 3x3, 5x5, 7x7, e.t.c. Can we do a similar procedure for a specific segment in neighborhoods of different size (approximately) with an time efficient way like in the link above?

Best regards,

Thoth

[image]

**PS:** Any questions are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find the indices of the neighbors of a specific area, you can do the following:

```
%# input: lblImg - image where pix(x,y) is the index of the segment
targetSegment = 4;
%# grow the segment by 2 pixels, since I assume the boundary in between is 1 pixel wide
msk = imdilate(lblImg == targetSegment,strel('disk',2));
msk(lblImg == targetSegment | lblImg == 0) = false; %# remove original cell, and boundary

%# retrieve the list of neighbors
listOfNeighbors = unique(lblImg(msk));
```

You can, of course, do this for all the segments in parallel, and create an adjacency matrix. Dilation is a local maximum operation, so it will make labels of different indices overlap.

```
 dilImg = imdilate(lblImg, strel('disk',2));
 msk = dilImg ~= lblImg & lblImg > 0; %# assume indices are all positive

 %# msk contains the indices of pixels where dilation
 %# has created an overlap between segments.

 rowColIdx = unique( [dilImg(msk), lblImg(msk)], 'rows');

 %# create adjacency matrix. Due to the nature of imdilate, this will fill in 
 %# only the values below the diagonal.
 %# adjacencyMatrix = adjacencyMatrix + adjacencyMatrix.' would fix that.
 nLabels = max(lblImg(:));
 adjacencyMatrix = sparse(rowColIdx(:,1),rowColIdx(:,2),ones(size(rowColIdx,1),1),...
   nLabels, nLabels);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will mark the post as answered as soon as I will be sure that I have not any questions. Thanks again!:)